# Minimum runs to Mega Satan?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

### Spoiler Alert...

(For a 7 month old game.)

In the sense that the minimum required runs to beat Mum's heart is 2:

1. Beat Mum - unlocks womb.
2. Beat Mum's heart.

The following hand waving occurs:

- You get the required deal with the angel/devil every time.
- You win every run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute minimum run involves the following:

- Defeat Mom - Unlocks womb
- In a single run:

  1. Defeat Mom's Heart and get an angel room or devil room (Requires luck). Take the trapdoor/beam of light to Sheol/Cathedral.
  2. With a teleportation item, teleport to the I AM ERROR room (Requires extraordinary luck or a *lot* of teleporting) and take the trapdoor/beam of light to the Dark Room/Chest.
  3. Defeat The Lamb/Blue Baby - Unlocks the Mega Satan door
- In the final run

  1. Find 2 angel rooms and, in each, bomb the angel statue and defeat the angel. This gets you Key Piece 1 and Key Piece 2, which combine to form the key.
  2. Do the same thing as in the previous run. When you reach the Dark Room/Chest, the Mega Satan door will be there, and the Key will unlock it.

The minimum run that requires as little luck as possible is:

- Defeat Mom - unlocks Womb
- Defeat Mom's Heart 10 times - Unlocks permanent entrances to Sheol and the Cathedral.
- Defeat Satan 5 times - Unlocks the Negative
- In a single run

  1. Find 2 angel rooms, as above.
  2. Beat Mom and get the Negative.
  3. Beat It Lives and go down.
  4. Beat Satan and touch the chest.

Comment: You'd need a third run in the first method. The Satan door doesn't appear until you've beaten The Lamb or ???

Comment: OK, I've fixed that